# De-duplicate rows in GCP Big Query (SQL) based on two columns

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to output all columns while have certain rows de-duplicated.
Everything I've tried doesn't seem to get anywhere close.

```
SELECT * FROM `project.dataset.table`
??
```

- de-duplicate based on Name
- where the chosen row to keep when de-duplicating Column1 uses the most recent date in LastUpdateDate
- the row to keep will always be the last row (with the duplicate value at Name) as it would have been appended to the table later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using `ARRAY_AGG`:

```
with TestData as (
  select 'Tom' as Name, '1' as Phone, timestamp('2020-01-01 00:00:00') as LastUpdateDate 
  union all
  select 'Tom' as Name, '2' as Phone, timestamp('2020-01-02 00:00:00') as LastUpdateDate
  union all
  select 'Eva' as Name, '3' as Phone, timestamp('2020-01-03 00:00:00') as LastUpdateDate
  union all
  select 'Eva' as Name, '4' as Phone, timestamp('2020-01-04 00:00:00') as LastUpdateDate
)
SELECT deduplicated.* FROM (
  SELECT ARRAY_AGG(t ORDER BY t.LastUpdateDate DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)] as deduplicated
  FROM TestData as t 
  GROUP BY Name
)
```

Comment: The subquery is unnecessary.  You can use `(ARRAY_AGG(t ORDER BY t.LastUpdateDate DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)]).*`.

Comment: Thanks Sergey - exactly what I needed!

Comment: Consider accepting the answer then! :-)